# How long does memory leak itself exist in C++ and how does an equivalent Java program differ?

Tags: java, c++, memory-leaks

Here is a simple piece of code in C++ that only dynamically allocates memory for an instance of some class named Foo and forgets to free the memory afterward. Let's assume Foo is very simple.

```
int main() {
  Foo *abcd = new Foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Since the program terminates, is it really memory leaking? **If I re-run this program**, will the previously allocated memory be available for allocation?

This is the equivalent Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Foo abcd = new Foo();
}
```

Since the program terminates fast, what if the **garbage collector** does not have enough time to free the memory? **If I re-run this program**, will the previously allocated memory be available for allocation?

Comment: Smells of homework and elderberries.

Comment: You are free to ignore it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both cases, when the program finishes, all the memory used is reclaimed.
Memory leaks are most critical in programs which run for a very long time (days, weeks, months, years even).